# XLL function arguments signature type

Tags: c++, excel, arguments, add-in, xll

I'm used [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2007/12/09/building-an-excel-xll-in-c-c-with-vs-2008.aspx) example for build XLL for Excel using C++.
I'm created own function which take 2 double args and return string:

```
 __declspec(dllexport) LPXLOPER12 WINAPI PTstate (double P, double T)
{
       static XLOPER12 xResult;
       xResult.xltype = xltypeStr;  
       debugPrintf("P = %d\n", P);
       debugPrintf("T = %d\n", T);
      Calculate(P, T);
      xResult.val.str = L"\013Calculated";
      return(LPXLOPER12) &xResult;
}
```

Function definition:

```
{
              L"PTstate",                 // Function name/ordinal
              L"UBB",                    // Func signature type **U - XLOPER12, BB - P and T double**
              L"PTstate",                 // Func name in Func wizard
              L"P, T",             // Arg name in Func wizard
              L"1",                      // Function type
              L"SimpleXll2007",           // Category in Func wizard
              L"",                       // Shortcut (commands only)
              L"",                       // Help topic
              L"",  // Func help in Func wizard
              L"",          // Arg help in Func wizard
              L""           // Arg help in Func wizard       
       },
```

If P = 100,345 T = 200,567 I'm getting P = 2061584302 and T = -584115552 in output - I've used debugPrintf function.
When function args is long:

```
__declspec(dllexport) LPXLOPER12 WINAPI PTstate (long P, long T)
```

and function signature "UJJ" I try P = 100,345 T = 200,567 I'm getting P=100 and T = 201.

So, which right function signature I must use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right way - use breakpoints to view variables values.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the comma is being interpreted as a decimal point.

Comment: I'm use debugPrintf  as debugPrintf("P = %d\n", P); debugPrintf("T = %d\n", T) It is right?

Comment: Dunno. I never use debugPrintf. Why not set a breakpoint in the debugger instead?

Comment: Oops. You right! I set breakpoint and view variables values - this is OK. Well I use debugPrintf incorrect. Thanks.

Comment: Well. Add your comment to your answer and I mark this as answer